# UICollecionView inside UITableView. How to handle selections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am making a form with a `tableView` with multiple kind of cell types. One of these types contains an UICollectionView with buttons to select some answers.

What I need is to be able to hide or show rows in the table, regarding on the answers.
For example: when answer to question 2 is "No", question 3 is not showing anymore.

But I don't know how to make that tableview knows what's being selected in one of it's cells

In the cell that contains the UICollectionView I have this method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = optionsCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath!) as! OptionsCollectionViewCell
    let data = cell.itemButton.titleLabel?.text
    selectedItem = data

}
```

But I don't know how to automatically pass it to the tableview so it knows what rows to show or hide... Any idea?

this is my `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if sortedFixedContentType.count != 0 {
        let item = sortedFixedContentType[indexPath.row]

        switch item.typeId {
        case "42":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormFileCell", for: indexPath) as! FormFileCell
            return cell;
        case "39":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormExpenseTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! FormExpenseTypeCell


            return cell;
        case "86":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormExpensePaymentModeCell", for: indexPath) as! FormExpensePaymentModeCell
            return cell;
        case "87":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormExpenseFileTypeCell", for: indexPath) as! FormExpenseFileTypeCell

            return cell;
        case "88":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FormProviderCell", for: indexPath) as! FormProviderCell
            return cell;
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BaseFormCell
            cell.idLabel.text = item.htmlType
            return cell
        }
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BaseFormCell
        cell.idLabel.text = ""
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create your delegate and when user clicks on collection view cell, call that delegate in your ViewController where you have placed your TableView delegate and data source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Four steps to do this :-

1.First create a protocol lets say 'CustomCellDelegate'  in your custom cell where you are using collectionview inside and create a variable that will hold the custom delegate just to give a example suppose your cell name is CustomCell create a CustomCellDelegate and declare it as customDelegate

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate : class {
    func Method1()
}

class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    var customDelegate : CustomCellDelegate?
}
```

2.Then you need to fire that delegate from CustomCell class collectionview delegate method didSelectItemAt like this

```
extension CustomCell : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let delegate = customDelegate {
            delegate.Method1()
        }
    }
}
```

3.Third assign the customDelegate to the view controller where you want to get the delegate for example myViewController here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customeCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.customDelegate = self // myViewController
    return cell
}
```

4.Handle the delegate in your view controller like this

```
extension myViewController : CustomCellDelegate {
    func Method1() {
        print("Method 1 called")
    }
}
```

I Hope this will solve your problem let me know if you find this answer helpful. **Cheers!!**

Comment: yes this seems to get me closer!! But I'm sorry, I don't know exactly how protocols work, therefore I don't know when 'method1' gets called. I followed your steps but when I select some item nothing gets printed so I guess I must be missing out something

Comment: "how protocols work" are hard to understand if you're a beginner but do some research you'll get through it.

Comment: method1 will get called from collectionview cell and refect in your view controller where you set cell.customDelegate = self.

Comment: This is what I needed, I'll do some research to get even closer. Thank you very much!